# Java RS232 Comm on Vista-64 bit

Tags: java, serial-port, vista64

We have a Java application which needs to communicate with a peripheral device over Virtual Serial COM port. We use the RS232 Java COMM API (javax.comm.properties, comm.jar, win32com.dll) to achieve the same. Currently the code works fine on Windows XP 32-bit, Vista 32-bit and Windows 7. However we are having a problem trying to communicate on Vista 64-bit. I read from the Java forums that there is no 64-bit support for the Java COMM API

I was wondering if anyone was facing a similar situation and were able to resolve the same in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [RXTX library](http://rxtx.org/).  It's an open source alternative to Sun's Comm API.  I haven't used it on a 64-bit machine, but it generally has better Windows support than Sun's version.